# customizing append data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have my data appended in table in my view but i want to show part of my data customized instead of just returning database data.

## Image = 1000 words

[image: one]

## explanation

I have currently return 3 data from my database `id, title & price` what I want is:

1. instead of showing `id's` show `checkbox`
2. instead of show `0` show `input field`

**I actually just need to return titles that's all.**

## Code

`HTML`

```
<div class="mt-20 options"></div>
```

`AJAX`

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('select[name="options"]').on('change', function() {
            var addressID = $(this).val();
            if(addressID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '{{ url('admin/getoptions') }}/'+encodeURI(addressID),
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {

                        //this is the part that appends my table
                        $('div.options').append('<div class="mb-20"><h4>Check mark your needed options only</h4></div>'+
                          '<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">'+
                          '<thead>'+
                            '<th class="text-center">Check</th>'+
                            '<th class="text-center">Title</th>'+
                            '<th class="text-center">Price</th>'+
                          '</thead>'+
                          '<tbody></tbody>'+
                          '</table>');

                        // 2. Loop through all entries
                        var keys = ['id', 'title', 'price'];
                        data.forEach(function(row) {
                          var $row = $('<tr />');

                          keys.forEach(function(key) {
                            $row.append('<td>' + row[key] + '</td>');
                          });

                          $('#table tbody').append($row);
                        });
                        //
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('div.options').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

> PS: it's not related to my question but just to avoid unnecessary
>   questions i am using laravel, that's why you see `{{...}}` in my Ajax
>   code.

## Question

1. How can I have my custom fields in appended table?

Comment: You're already building the markup for the table with jQuery. Just check the `key`, and in case of `id` and `price` add the markup for the inputs instead of only the content of `row[key]`

Comment: @Andreas you mean i make 3 `$row.append`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I added two more append row before and after my `forEach` and limited my data to title only.

#### Before

```
var keys = ['id', 'title', 'price'];
```

#### After

```
var keys = ['title'];
```

#### Before

```
keys.forEach(function(key) {
  $row.append('<td>' + row[key] + '</td>');
});
```

#### After

```
//added new row before forEach
$row.append('<td class="text-center" width="50"><label class="switch switch-small"><input type="checkbox" /><span><input class="form-control" type="text" name="optionID[]" value="'+row['id']+'"></span></label></td>');
keys.forEach(function(key) {
  $row.append('<td>' + row[key] + '</td>');
});
//added new row after forEach
$row.append('<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control" placeholder="if fill this price, the price will add to product price when user select it." type="number" name="optionPRICE[]"></td>');
```

## Final code

```
success:function(data) {
    // $('div.options').empty();

    $('div.options').append('<div class="mb-20"><h4>Check mark your needed options only</h4></div>'+
      '<table id="table" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive">'+
      '<thead>'+
        '<th width="50" class="text-center">Check</th>'+
        '<th class="text-center">Title</th>'+
        '<th class="text-center">Price</th>'+
      '</thead>'+
      '<tbody></tbody>'+
      '</table>');

    // 2. Loop through all entries
    var keys = ['title'];
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      var $row = $('<tr />');

      $row.append('<td class="text-center" width="50"><label class="switch switch-small"><input type="checkbox" /><span><input class="form-control" type="text" name="optionID[]" value="'+row['id']+'"></span></label></td>');
      keys.forEach(function(key) {
        $row.append('<td>' + row[key] + '</td>');
      });
      $row.append('<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control" placeholder="if fill this price, the price will add to product price when user select it." type="number" name="optionPRICE[]"></td>');

      $('#table tbody').append($row);
    });
}
```

Hope it help others.